# rdata: applying dist() over a data frame's rows

Tags: r, rdata

I can do this:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
p1 <- subset(data, player_name == 'Player1')
p2 <- subset(data, player_name == 'Player2')

dist(rbind(p1[,c("gp","points")], p2[,c("gp","chances_for","chances_for_help")]))
```

And I get my distance. But `data` has over 1000 rows in it, and I want for each row the ten most similar records based on GP and point, but I can't quite figure it out.

Something like:

```
apply(data, 1, function(p) {
    dist(rbind(p, data))
})
```

But obviously that's not working. Is there a quick fix here?

Example data:

```
player_name,gp,points
Player 1,82,95
Player 2,80,88
Player 3,81,84
Player 4,82,90
Player 5,82,77
```

Comment: I think doing `dist` on the whole set once and then picking the lowest cases from each row would be more appropriate than running `dist` `nrow` times.

Comment: Any quick example of that?

Comment: `out <- as.matrix(dist(dat[,c("gp","points")]))` and then `apply(out, 1, function(x) colnames(out)[order(x)[2:4]] )` for the closest 3 matches? (the closest match will be the same row, hence starting indexing at 2). I doubt that is hugely efficient but that sort of logic.

Comment: I see what this is giving me, but it's giving me the values in a matrix. How could I apply this back to the original `data` set so it's tied by player name?

Comment: `apply(out, 1, function(x) order(x)[2:4] )` returns the row numbers of the original `dat` dataset that are the closest matches.

Comment: Do you mind me emailing you?

Comment: Please don't - someone will no doubt be able to help here in good time.

Answer (score 0):

@thelatemail has basically given you the full answer. So going further into his approach you can extend it in the following way (I'm using `dplyr` library).

Firstly create a row id:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% mutate(rowid = row_number())
```

...and transform the distance data into a data frame:

```
dist_data <- as.data.frame(t(apply(out, 1, function(x) colnames(out)[order(x)[2:4]])))
dist_data <- dist_data %>% mutate(rowid = row_number())
```

Then you can simply join on the `rowid`

```
data <- data %>% left_join(dist_data, by="rowid")
```

To add the names of the players, you just have to create some kind of player index data frame and do some more joins using the same idea:

```
data$V1 <- as.numeric(data$V1)
data$V2 <- as.numeric(data$V2)
data$V3 <- as.numeric(data$V3)

# now we have to remap the V1, V2, V3 to the player_name and id's..
# we can do this by create a name dataset with the indexes...
name_index <- dplyr::select(data, player_name, rowid)

data %>% 
  left_join(rename(name_index, closest_name1=player_name, V1=rowid)) %>% 
  left_join(rename(name_index, closest_name2=player_name, V2=rowid)) %>%
  left_join(rename(name_index, closest_name3=player_name, V3=rowid)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-V1, -V2, -V3)
```

output:

```
  player_name gp points rowid closest_name1 closest_name2 closest_name3
1    Player 1 82     95     1      Player 3      Player 2      Player 2
2    Player 2 80     88     2      Player 3      Player 3      Player 1
3    Player 3 81     84     3      Player 1      Player 4      Player 4
4    Player 4 82     90     4      Player 1      Player 1      Player 2
5    Player 5 82     77     5      Player 2      Player 2      Player 3
```